# Ошибка при передаче ссылок в конструктор класса

Tags: c++, arduino

Класс InfoMenu:

```
class InfoMenu : public Menu  
{
    public:
        InfoMenu(float& voltage, float& target_voltage, int& pwm) : voltage(voltage), target_voltage(target_voltage), charge_procent(pwm){

        }
        virtual RenderResult getRenderInformation();
        virtual float getResult();
        virtual void onControllerEvent(Controller* controller);
    private:
        float& voltage;
        float& target_voltage;
        int& charge_procent;
};

RenderResult InfoMenu::getRenderInformation() 
{
    RenderResult result;

    result.label = "volt.:  " + TimeManager::getTimeFromStart();

    result.text = String(this->voltage) + '-' + String(this->target_voltage)+" "+String(this->charge_procent);

    return result;
}

float InfoMenu::getResult() 
{
    return 0.0;
}


void InfoMenu::onControllerEvent(Controller* controller) 
{
    
}
```

Класс Menu:

```
struct RenderResult
{
    String label;
    String text;
};

class Menu {
    public:
        virtual RenderResult getRenderInformation() = 0;
        virtual float getResult() = 0;
        virtual void onControllerEvent(Controller* controller) = 0;
};
```

Класс AlternatorController:

```
class AlternatorController  
{
    public:
        AlternatorController(int pin) : alt_pin(pin) {

        }

        float getAlternatorVoltage();
        void setTargetVoltage(float voltage);
        void adjustVoltage();
        void setPwmK(int pwm_k);
        int getAlternatorLoad();

        float targetVoltage = 0.0;
        float currentVoltage = 0.0;
        int current_load = 0;
    private:
        float getVoltage();
        int pwm_k = 1;
        int alt_pin = 0;

};
```

Клиентский код:

```
Menu* m = new InfoMenu(&alter_controller.currentVoltage, &alter_controller.targetVoltage, &alter_controller.current_load);
```

Ошибка:

> no instance of constructor "InfoMenu::InfoMenu" matches the argument
> list -- argument types are: (float *, float *, int *)

Почему так происходит? Ведь передаю все верно, вроде как

Comment: Уберите `&` из вызова конструктора. `&` создает указатели, а ваши параметры не указатели.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

операция `&` для существующей переменной берет её адрес, а когда создаете переменную с `&` амперсанд будет показывать что это ссылочный тип, посмотрите пример в котором показывается в зависимости от передаваемого параметра какая будет вызываться перегрузка

```
#include <iostream>


void foo(int* arg)
{
  std::cout << "pass by pointer\n";
}

void foo(int& arg)
{
  std::cout << "pass by reference\n";
}


int main()
{
  int x = 5;
  foo(&x);   // pass by pointer
  foo(x);    // pass by reference

  return 0;
}
```